# How to make it more safe?

Tags: haskell

I have following function:

```
isElemChar :: Char -> Bool
isElemChar x = elem x ['A'..'Z'] || elem x ['a'..'z']
```

When I try to use the function as follow:

```
isElemChar 5
```

Then I've got the exception:

```
<interactive>:73:12: error:
    * No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal `5'
    * In the first argument of `isElemChar', namely `5'
      In the expression: isElemChar 5
      In an equation for `it': it = isElemChar 5
*Cipher Data.Char> isElemChar 'a'
```

How to make the function more safe? Which would be the right approach to make it to total function?

I could use the `Maybe` datatype, but do not know how to implement it.

Comment: You're trying to pass a number to a function that only accepts `Char`s. Try `isElemChar '5'`.

Comment: If the user would pass 5 instead '5' how to handle the exception?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function *is* safe. The "exception" you mention is actually a compile-time error, which is exactly the time you want errors.

This is slightly hidden by the fact you're at an interactive prompt, but if you wrote the program `safe.hs`....

```
isElemChar :: Char -> Bool
isElemChar x = elem x ['A'..'Z'] || elem x ['a'..'z']

main = print $ isElemChar 5
```

... and you tried to compile it...

```
ghc safe.hs
```

... you would get a similar error

```
safe.hs:5:27: error:
    • No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘5’
    • In the first argument of ‘isElemChar’, namely ‘5’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘isElemChar 5’
      In the expression: print $ isElemChar 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make the function more safe, this is not python, the functions params have a type, so your code will just give you a `compile error`.
If you are dealing with `IO` you will always get an `IO([Char])` or a `IO(Char)`.